# iOS why NSParagraphStyle resets the original text styles

Tags: ios, nsattributedstring, nsparagraphstyle

I use `UILabel`'s `attributedText` to load a HTML string, for example:

```
<p style="text-align: center;">sometext</p>
```

And I use `NSParagraphStyle` to change the `line-height` of all elements of this HTML.

```
NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [NSMutableParagraphStyle new];
paragraphStyle.minimumLineHeight = 20; // line-height: 20;

[attributedString addAttribute:NSParagraphStyleAttributeName
                         value:paragraphStyle
                         range:NSMakeRange(0, attributedString.length)];
```

It works. But it will reset the `text-align` to left.

Comment: That's normal behavior, attributes work like a Dictionary in a range. So you just override the `NSParagraphStyleAttributeName` value. Instead, enumerate the attributes looking for the paragraph style, and change its line height.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Attributes works like a Dictionary: Key/Value in a defined range.
There is unicity of the key, so you are overriding the value without copying its previous style.

To do what you want, you need to enumerate the attributed string looking for the `NSParagraphStyleAttributeName` and modify it if necessary.

```
[attributedString enumerateAttribute:NSParagraphStyleAttributeName inRange:NSMakeRange(0, [attributedString length]) options:0 usingBlock:^(id  _Nullable value, NSRange range, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
    if ([value isKindOfClass:[NSParagraphStyle class]]) {
        NSMutableParagraphStyle *style = [value mutableCopy];
        style.minimumLineHeight = 20;
        [attributedString addAttribute:NSParagraphStyleAttributeName value:style range:range];
    }
}];
```

Comment: it's useful for me. but the effect is not same as adding attribute dirctily. i will figure out it by this way. thanks!

Comment: "but the effect is not same as adding attribute dirctily.": I said why you can't do it. The other way is to modify directly the html and apply one (if possible, I'm not familiar with html tags).